# How do you stop a remove in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have collection of sprites and a collection of frames (each frame has an instance of a sprite in it) and I don't want to remove a sprite from the sprites collection if it is used in the frames collection.

I have looked into listening for the remove event and should be able to detect if it is in the  frames collection, but without using an exception doubt that I could prevent the removal of the sprite.

What event should I be looking for, or should I be looking for something a little more complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone source for `remove` method:

```
     remove: function(models, options) {
        models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
        options || (options = {});
        var i, l, index, model;
        for (i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++) {
          model = this.get(models[i]);
          if (!model) continue;
          delete this._byId[model.id];
          delete this._byId[model.cid];
          index = this.indexOf(model);
          this.models.splice(index, 1);
          this.length--;
          if (!options.silent) {
            options.index = index;
            model.trigger('remove', model, this, options);
          }
          this._removeReference(model);
        }
        return this;
      },
```

So, there isn't 'out-of-the-box' way do prevent deletion of element.
To achieve this, you can, extends `Backbone.Collection` and override `remove` method:

```
  var SpriteCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    remove: function(attrs, options) {
      //Some your checks
      return Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.call(this, options);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks good so I'll give it a shot shortly and accept it if it works

Comment: You need to pass the models through to be deleted in your answer (and you'd called them attr's) so I've corrected that and accepted your answer.